# RDS Parameter Group

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, rds

I'm using Amazon RDS , and create parameter group to version MySql5.5.
I was wondering whether it is possible to enable innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog on an RDS instance somehow? The GUI doesn't seem to allow this.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the GUI only shows parameters that can be changed, so no, you cannot change that on RDS.

Also, it seems this parameter is deprecated for current versions of MySQL. According to the official documentation on MySQL site:

> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog
>
> As of MySQL 5.6.3, innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog is deprecated and
>   will be removed in a future MySQL release.

So that would be a likely reason why this parameter cannot be changed.

Cheers,